# Flex Button CSS skinning

Tags: apache-flex, skinning

I have a CSS file containing the following definition :

```
.Tab{
    up-skin:Embed(skinClass='XUpSkin');
    over-skin:Embed(skinClass='XOverSkin');
    disabled-skin:Embed(skinClass='XDisabledSkin');
}
```

And a Flex file :

```
<mx:Button id="b1" style="Tab"/>
```

Now, I want to use the disabled-skin defined in the CSS, as the upSkin of **b1**.
So something like

```
b1.setStyle("upSkin","Tab.disabled-skin");
```

But I am struggling with the exact syntax of the second argument for setStyle.
What should I use for the second argument for setStyle method?

Answer (score 1):

b1.setStyle("upSkin", b1.getStyle("disabled-skin") );

Comment: Shouldn't that 2nd arg be `b1.getStyle("disabled-skin")`?

Comment: doh... yes it should! Edited to reflect that. Good catch!

Comment: So if I say b1.setStyle("upSkin", b1.getStyle("disabled-skin") );,
then upSkin and disabledSkin for b1 become same. So, at a later point of time I want to access the original upSkin, how do I?

Comment: keep hold of it until you need it again. If you are wanting to play with the skins a lot, create a class that extends Button, override createChildren and store the three skins in internal variables. Then you can do things like.
b1.setStyle( "upSkin", b1.myDisabledSkin );
b1.setStyle( "upSkin", b1.myUpSkin );